# Get plugin to background of page

Tags: plugins, theme-development, css

Sorry for asking 2 questions in one day, but I can't figure this out and couldn't find anything on internet as well.

With wordpress I created a simple website with a sticky menu. Everything worked fine, until I started adding a google maps plugin and a photo gallery plugin. Now, if I scroll down, the output of the plugins (photo's and a map) cover my menu. (It's on this website: http://urbanbeeing.com/about - scroll down to see what's wrong)

I added my css file properly within the functions file:

```
function komErbij_res() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', komErbij_res());
```

I guess this has something to do with the order of calling the stylesheets and plugins, but I don't have any idea how to solve this.

If someone could help me, you would make my day :)

Rik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS file is loading fine, yes.

But you need to add some more to it.

`z-index` is used to say where to place an element in the 'layers', when elements overlap.

The higher the `z-index` the higher it will appear.

add `z-index:10` to the header:

```
header.site-header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    z-index: 10; /* New style */
}
```

In your case, a `z-index` of `1` will do it, though.

Comment: Ah yes, tried it, and it works. Thank you! I can only accept your answer in 6 minutes though